# OCaml Style for a function that merges two sorted lists into one sorted list

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml and I am auditing a class. I have a homework prompt that reads:
 "merge xs ys takes two integer lists, each sorted in increasing order,
 and returns a single merged list in sorted order."

I have successfully written a function that works:

```
let rec merge xs ys = match xs with
  | [] -> ys
  | hxs::txs -> if hxs <= (match ys with
    | [] -> hxs
    | hys::tys -> hys)
      then hxs :: merge txs ys 
      else match ys with
      | [] -> xs
      | hys::tys -> hys :: merge xs tys  in
merge [-1;2;3;100] [-1;5;1001]
;;
```

I would like to know if my code is considered to be in acceptable OCaml style? I want to avoid forming any bad habits. It feels compositionaly dense, but maybe that's because I'm still not used to OCaml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally find it hard to follow `if hxs <= (match ...)`, and it's difficult to format it nicely. So I would probably write

```
 ...
 let hys =
   match ys with
   | [] -> hxs
   | hys :: _ -> hys
 in
 if hxs < hys then
    hxs :: merge txs ys
 ...
```

However, I think it might be even better to match both `xs` and `ys` at the same time:

```
let rec merge xs ys =
   match xs, ys with
   | [], _ -> ys
   | _, [] -> xs
   | hx :: txs, hy :: tys ->
       if hx < hy then hx :: merge txs ys else hy :: merge xs tys
```

I think this captures the symmetry of the problem better.

I think it's good when the length of the code matches well with the simplicity of the problem it solves. Merging is simple to state, and so the code shouldn't need to be long (it seems to me).

Comment: If you want to play clever, you can also formulate the first two cases as a single `| ([], rest) | (rest, []) -> rest`.

Comment: that's great thank you. I felt like there must be a way to refactor all the matches I was using. That's a great example.